# Reduce en python

Tags: python, reduce

Cordial saludo

Tengo una consulta para ustedes comunidad

Tengo estas lista

```
lista2=['Mexico', 'Colombia', 'Brasil', 'Venezuela', 'Bolivia', 'Argentina', 'Uruguay', 'Peru', 'Paraguay', 'Chile','a']
```

Mediante una función de Python, creé una lista con el número de a's en cada palabra de la lista con el siguiente ciclo

```
def contarconfor (lista):
  for x in lista:
    countar = 0
    for g in x:
        if g == "a":
            countar = countar + 1
    print(countar)
    #return(countar)
```

contarconfor(Palabras)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego lo requiero Utilizar  la función reduce() para determinar el total de a's que hay en la lista2.

he intentado con

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me aparece este error y no he podido conseguir mi resultado

Alguna sugerencia

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Es necesario usar `reduce`? Hay un modo muy fácil de hacer lo que quieres: `''.join(lista2).count("a")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El punto es que `reduce` requiere una función con dos argumentos:

**functools.reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])**

> Aplicar una función de dos argumentos acumulativos a los elementos de
> iterable, de izquierda a derecha, para reducir los itables a un solo
> valor. Por ejemplo, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calcula
> ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5). El argumento de la izquierda, x, es el valor
> acumulado y el de la derecha, y, es el valor de actualización del
> iterable. Si el initializer opcional está presente, se coloca antes de
> los ítems de la iterable en el cálculo, y sirve como predeterminado
> cuando la iterable está vacía. Si no se da el initializer y el
> iterable contiene sólo un elemento, se retorna el primer elemento.

Siguiendo este modelo, los dos argumentos de la función van a ser:

- La suma acumulada hasta el momento (un entero).
- El texto a examinar para contar las "a".

La función es:

```
def contar_letra(acc: int, texto: str) -> int:
    return acc + sum(1 for x in texto.lower() if x == 'a')
```

Para contar las letras recorreremos el texto (convertido a minúsculas) *generando* un `1` por cada letra `a` y agregandole el total acumulado (viene en `acc`).

Con eso, lo pedido es:

```
from functools import reduce

lista2=['Mexico', 'Colombia', 'Brasil', 'Venezuela', 'Bolivia', 'Argentina', 'Uruguay', 'Peru', 'Paraguay', 'Chile','a']

def contar_letra(acc, texto):
    return acc + sum(1 for x in texto.lower() if x == 'a')

total = reduce(contar_letra, lista2, 0)
print(total)
```

produce:

```
11

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Versión compacta**

Puedes compactar lo anterior. No queda tan legible para mi gusto, pero ahi va:

```
total = reduce(lambda acc, texto: acc + sum(1 for letra in texto.lower() if letra == 'a'), lista2, 0)
print(total)
```

Se trata simplemente de convertir la función en un lambda.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Candid Moe

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero que aproveches tu `for` dentro de tu función  `contarconfor` para que guardes los valores en una lista y después poder sumarlos para encontrar tu numero total de 'a' que se repite en tu lista.

Algo como:

```
lista2=['Mexico', 'Colombia', 'Brasil', 'Venezuela', 'Bolivia', 'Argentina', 'Uruguay', 'Peru', 'Paraguay', 'Chile','a']
a = list()
def contarconfor (lista):
  for x in lista:
    countar = 0
    for g in x:
        if g == "a":
            countar = countar + 1
    print(countar)
    a.append(countar)
    #return(countar)
```

Despues ya puedes obtener tu numero total de valores de 'a' que se encuentran en tu `lista2`:

```
contarconfor(lista2)
print("\nSum: ", sum(a))
```

Y el resultado de esto es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En mi ejercicio me piden utilizar reduce @Marcos Guerrero aunque con tu respuesta podre el reduce de esta forma   print (reduce(lambda a,b: a+b , a)).  Muchas gracias

Comment: Aunque cuando lo vuelvo a iterar con otra lista mantiene los valores de la anterior  iteracion